# Disabling double line spacing in code folding in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, configuration, folding

I use the code folding commands in Visual Studio 2008 all the time - e.g.

```
ctrl + m, ctrl + o  (collapse all)
ctrl + m, ctrl + m  (toggle expand/collapse of code block)
```

Visual Studio 2010 has the "improvement" that folded code now has a white space line between one block and the next.  e.g.

```
void function1()[+]{...}

void function2()[+]{...}
```

Instead of the VS2008 way

```
void function1()[+]{...}
void function2()[+]{...}
```

Anyone know how to prevent VS2010 from adding this whiteline space - it's extremely irritating!

Update:  it seems that lots of folks can't reproduce.  but since this question has got 6 up votes to date, I'm assuming that there are those who can.

C# users report that they can't reproduce.  I code in c++ exclusively and it's definitely a problem in c++.  Maybe I'll post a report to m$...

Comment: Send feedback to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: I don't want to have to sign up to a hotmail account just to have to submit a bug(feature?!).  I was hoping someone might know a workaround for the problem.

Comment: I've just started using StyleCop - this is one of the standard rules so I'm not surprised to see Visual Studio enforce it by default.  I am surprised that you can't turn it off, though.  I've had a look but haven't found a way to help.

Comment: @freefallr: I cannot reproduce your problem. I just get the whiteline exactly if there was a whiteline between the functions before the fold. Or did you mean that the fold included one additional whiteline in VS2008? Also, you do not need to make a hotmail account to post on connect!

Comment: don't put any whitelines between functions.  That's my whole point.  If I don't have whitelines between functions and I collapse the code, I get whitespace between functions!  Use a class declaration (like a COM activex ctrl, or a regular class with lots of functions in the class declaration.)

Comment: @freefallr: I said "exactly if" - If I don't add whitespaces, I don't get whitespaces in the collapsed version...

Comment: @freeallr: it is not necessary for you to sign up to a hotmail account in order to submit a bug. You can use any email address and associated with Live Passport. I can submit bugs to MS with my work email address, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your specific issue is addressed by installing the *[Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)*, but I just tested out the collapsed display in a C++ project in my install and it works as it used to in VS2008.  The *Productivity Power Tools* add a lot of other nice little features and fix some irritations in VS2010 that make them worth having anyways.

Additional note: We're running VS2010 Ultimate, although I wouldn't expect the edition to matter.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to award the points as time ran out before I revisited the question, but I'll award you the answer, as you're one of the few who correctly read the question and offered a sensible solution!!!

Comment: Tbh if you'd have written your question more carefully, with a complete file that produces this behaviour, and screenshots too, oh and your exact environment details might have helped... then you could have got a "sensible solution" quicker. It's little comments like yours above that make helpful people not want to help anymore :/

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce it. I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express.

```
namespace Bums
{
    class Bum1
    {
        void Lick1()
        {
            Lick2();
        }
        void Lick2()
        {
            Lick1();
        }
    }
    class Bum2
    {
        void Lick1()
        {
            Lick2();
        }
        void Lick2()
        {
            Lick1();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Pinky]

*(please no comments about how I should derive both classes from a base IBum interface)*

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010 professional and coding exclusively in c++

Comment: Well I also have Visual C++ 2010 Express installed, and I get the exact same behaviour as I did in C#. I can't believe there's a difference between Professional and Express in this regard, so what could it be? Why don't you post a complete file that fails, so I can test it on mine?

Answer (score -1):

Just to clarify, when you using 'ctrl + m, ctrl + o' or 'ctrl + m, ctrl + m' in visual studio 2010, then vs automatically add white space line between methods.

Suppose you have following class:

```
 public class VsSettings
 {
        void function1()
        {
        }
        void function2()
        {
        }
 }
```

And after click 'ctrl + m, ctrl + o' you see following:

```
 public class VsSettings
    {
        void function1()...

        void function2()...
    }
```

If so then try to reset visual studio settings(tools -> import and export settings) and disable external plugins(like resharper, etc..), because for me result always was following(with resharper enabled, without resharper, before settings reset, after settings reset):

```
  public class VsSettings
        {
            void function1()...    
            void function2()...
        }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I'm a C++ developer, and I don't use .NET or any plugins like resharper.

I've viewed files in other editors; there are no physical spaces inserted into the file, but, collapsing the code displays functions in double line spacing.

Comment: This happens after a clean install of VS2010, there are no imported settings.

Comment: Awesome but i've create c++ console project and cheched there, but collapsing work as expected.

Comment: I also can't reproduce the issue... do you have the SP installed?  I do not.

Comment: Try reproducing it with a class.  Others have determined that the question is valid.

Comment: Sorry but for me collapsing work without adding white space line even in class.